# Vim times out (Killed) in screen on CentOS server

Tags: vim, ssh, gnu-screen

I tend to work in screen and have several files open in vim.  I control-z and then use fg to move between them.

After the recent update, idle vim instances "time out" and are killed.  My SSH connection and screen are still connected.

This breaks up my workflow because I need to keep re-opening the files in vim if I'm away from my workstation for more than a few minutes.

I had this problem in the past, and figured out how to turn off this feature - but it's been a couple of years and I can't remember if it's a vim, ssh, screen or other config issue.

I figure that the recent update may have overwritten config changes I made in the past.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Further info - caught it in action:   
Vim: Caught deadly signal TERM
Vim: Finished.
Terminated   -- after bringing the file back to the foreground to edit it.  Did a couple of searches and Vim just quit with the message above.

Comment: Also - might be relevant.  The server in question is a GoDaddy el-cheapo virtual server running Centos and CPanel

Comment: "Can anyone point me in the right direction?" Yes: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues